# Restore the original color of UINavigation Controller

Tags: iphone

I am changing the color of UINavugation bar to red by

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

but after few seconds I want to restore it to the default color of UINavigation bar.
Please help

Comment: Use NSTimer to change the color after a few seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excuse me if I'm oversimplifying the problem, but it seems you could save the default color into a variable, and just set it back when you need to.

You can user a performSelector call to delay the color change.

i.e.

```
//save the default color into a previously declared UIColor variable
defaultColor =  self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;

//set the new color
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

//set the restore method to fire in 3 seconds
[self performSelector:@selector(restoreNavColor) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

and somewhere in your class;

```
- (void)restoreNavColor {

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = defaultColor;

}
```

This will work regardless of whether you've previously modified the default color of the nav bar or not, and thus should work for your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

any of these;

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Thanks,

Satya

Answer (score 2):

set the color to nil like this. Maybe it would help.

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to call the method after a few seconds...

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(changeColor) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

```
[timer fire];
```

in changeColor method change the color to default and then invalidate the timer.

Comment: hi,  I think he is asking about how to change the color to default.

Comment: yeah thanks....but he has mentioned "after a few seconds".. tatz why i wrote the code using NSTimer...